# Error de conexión de Base de Datos al ejecutar mi programa en el cliente - C# y SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-express

Desarrollé una aplicación en C# y Sql Server 2014. La instalé sin ningún problema pero al ejecutarla me sale el error que de no encuentra el servidor o que no estaba accesible .[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estuve insvestigando y una opción es utilizar Sql Server Compact pero debo reescribir varias cosas del programa por lo que pensé que quizá sería mas fácil y rápido instalar una instancia de Sql Server Express en el cliente (no me parece lo mas apropiado pero dispongo de poco tiempo y al cliente le va a servir en un futuro para otro proyecto mas grande que tiene pensado).
Probé en una máquina virtual hacer esto pero no me sigue dando el mismo error ya que no sé de qué manera relacionar la cadena de conexión de mi software con la instancia de Sql instalada en el cliente.

Comment: ¿qué dice en detalles?, eso resuelve el problema la mayoría de las veces

Comment: en detalles describe el error de conexion:  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): 
Error relacionado con la red o específico de la instancia mientras se establecía una conexión con el servidor SQL Server. 
No se encontró el servidor o éste no estaba accesible. 
Compruebe que el nombre de la instancia es correcto y que SQL Server está configurado para admitir conexiones remotas. 
(provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - No se puede ubicar la instalación del tiempo de ejecución de la 
base de datos local.

Comment: Compruebe que SQL Server Express se ha instalado correctamente y que se ha habilitado la característica de tiempo 
de ejecución de la base de datos local.) ---> 
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado

ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
Error Number:2,State:0,Class:20

Comment: Tu cadena de conexion cambia de pc en pc.. cambiaste la cadenade conexion?

Comment: Claro, pero yo a la pc del cliente solo llevo el instalador e instalo una instancia de Sql Server Express. En mi programa pongo una cadena de conexión al servidor local (con un "." (punto) en este caso)

Comment: Abre el `Administrador de Tareas` y dirígete al apartado de `Servicios` y verifica que el servicio `MSSQL$SQL2014` este en estado `Corriendo` `Iniciado`, en ocaciones el Sistema Operativo no carga bien los servicios, verifica a ver que tal.

Comment: Si ya verificaste que la cadena de conexión es correcta te recomiendo que revises  también que la pc a la cual le vas a instalar la aplicación tenga los `Frameworks`, para pruebas puedes colocar el nombre del servidor como: `(local)` prueba si conecta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que hice fue modificar el nombre del servidor de la cadena de conexion a `(local)` como me dijo @J. Rodriguez y luego creé un archivo de configuración que almacene esta cadena y se haga referencia a este archivo desde la Capa de Datos. Con esto me funcionó perfectamente.